# Rails Rspec - model attribute undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I keep getting the error undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass when I run my rspec on the Billing model. Below is my code for the model

```
class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :start_date, :end_date, presence: true
  validate :is_valid_date?

  def is_valid_date?
    errors.add(:start_date, 'must be in the past') if start_date > Time.current.to_date
    errors.add(:end_date, 'must be in the past') if end_date > Time.current.to_date
    errors.add(:end_date, 'must be more than or equal to start date') if start_date > end_date
  end
end
```

And this is my code for the rspec

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe FamilyBilling, type: :model do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:start_date) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:end_date) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:amount) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:hours) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:rate) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:processing_fee) }       
  it { should_not validate_presence_of(:tip) }
end
```

I get this error when I run rspec

```
Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/models/billing_spec.rb:8 # Billing should require start_date to be set
rspec ./spec/models/billing_spec.rb:9 # Billing should require end_date to be set
rspec ./spec/models/billing_spec.rb:10 # Billing should require amount to be set
rspec ./spec/models/billing_spec.rb:11 # Billing should require hours to be set
rspec ./spec/models/billing_spec.rb:12 # Billing should require rate to be set
rspec ./spec/models/billing_spec.rb:13 # Billing should require processing_fee to be set
rspec ./spec/models/billing_spec.rb:14 # Billing should not require tip to be set
```

and all of them show this error

```
Failure/Error: errors.add(:start_date, 'must be in the past') if start_date > Time.current.to_date

NoMethodError:
    undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Which line? Include the entire error so we don't have to guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom validator expects that both `start_date` and `end_date` must exist. If they don't exist that error is thrown - for example here: `start_date > Time.current.to_date`.

Therefore you should validate their presence explicitly and check that they are present in your custom validator:

```
class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :start_date, :end_date, presence: true
  validate :dates_valid?

  def dates_valid?
    errors.add(:start_date, 'must be in the past') if start_date && start_date > Time.current.to_date
    errors.add(:end_date, 'must be in the past') if end_date && end_date > Time.current.to_date
    errors.add(:end_date, 'must be more than or equal to start date') if start_date && end_date && start_date > end_date
  end
end
```

Comment: I do have the validate presence on both start_date and end_date and it is still giving me the error. I will update my question to include these changes

Comment: Did you also change the custom validator? I change the `if` conditions in my answer. Because you need to check that the date is not `nil`, for example like this: `if start_date && start_date > Time.current.to_date`

Comment: @Josiah is right, this should fix the issue. The presence validator is not guaranteed to run before your custom validator, so you still need to account for the case where `start_date` etc may be nil.

Comment: @spickermann sorry I didn't see the check. And yes it does work now! Thank you so much for your help!